# What is the easiest way to find out character repetition in a string using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string consist of 7 digits, I need a function that returns "true" if the string created by repetition of just 2 digits, something like :

```
check('9669669');  // true
check('0000001');  // true
check('5555555');  // false
check('1111123');  // false
```

I want to know the easiest way.
thanks.

Comment: Probably a RegEx, but I am not sure I can deduce the pattern from your examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, pushing unique characters in an array, and checking if it's length is 2

```
function check(str) {
    var arr = [], i = 0, parts = str.split('');

    for (var j=0; j<parts.length; j++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(parts[j]) === -1) arr.push(parts[j]);
    }

    return arr.length === 2;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrgdr2jj/)

or more fancy

```
function check(str) {
    return str.split('').reduce(function(p, c) {
        if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c); return p;
    }, []).length === 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the first character globally, twice.

```
function check2(str){
    var fun= function(s){
        return s.replace(RegExp(s.charAt(0), 'g'), '')
    };
    str= fun(str);
    return !!(str && fun(str)=== '');
}
```

var A= ['9669669', '0000001', '5555555', '1111123'];

**A.map(check2);**

/*  returned value: (Array) [true,true,false,false] */